# Vue2: Equivalent to this.$els

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In `Vue 1.x`, I made use of the following directive to select a node directly.

```
<tbody v-el:visible-columns>
```

Then later:

```
this.$els.visibleColumns
```

Is there a `Vue 2.x` way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, so it's been replaces by ref/$refs:

```
<tbody ref="visible-columns"> <!-- or ref="visibleColumns" //-->
```

and

```
this.$refs['visible-columns'] // or this.$refs.visibleColumns
```

Hope this helps!